# Custom compound view width not matching parent in TableRow

Tags: android, kotlin

I've created a custom view called SectionRowView which extends a ConstraintLayout which is as simple as:

```
class SectionRowView : ConstraintLayout {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.section_row_view, this)
    }
}
```

SectionRowView inflates it's view from sectionrowview.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container">


    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/topBorder" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="#979797"/>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBorder" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:text="test test test test test test"/>
</merge>
```

In a fragment I then add this custom view to a `TableRow` inside a `TableLayout`:

```
class CustomizeQuizFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customize_quiz, container, false)

        val tableView = view.findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.tableView)
        setupTable(tableView)

        return view
    }

    private fun setupTable(tableView: TableLayout) {

        val layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val tableRow = TableRow(context)
        tableRow.layoutParams = layoutParams
        val sectionView = SectionRowView(context)
        sectionView.layoutParams = layoutParams
        tableRow.addView(sectionView)
        tableView.addView(tableRow)
    }
}
```

The xml layout for my fragment looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
                                                   android:id="@+id/container">

    <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:textSize="32sp" android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" android:textColor="#3C6FF3"/>
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/tableView" android:background="#00EC0909"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:background="@drawable/customstartbutton"
            android:textColor="#EFFBFD" android:textAllCaps="false" android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I run this, I can see in the layout inspector that the SectionRowView's width is not extending to `match_parent` like it's told to. It's parent element the `TableRow` has a fullscreen width like its supposed to:

[image: Layout Inspector Screenshot]

Using SectionRowView inside of a LinearLayout works just fine with the width extending to full screen. It seems to only have trouble inside a TableRow.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe your main issue here is the merge tag inside sectionrowview.xml. I could be mistaken, but is the `SectionRowView` element in the hierarchy actually of type `ConstraintLayout` in the layout hierarchy?

Comment: How would I check the the type of SectionRowView from the layout inspector? sorry new to android studio.

Comment: Off the top of my head not sure, other than interacting with the line item for it in the layout hierarchy. I believe it allows you to inspect values of that layout element in another tab/tool window.

Comment: There's a field called `mLayerType` which is set to NONE. but I don't think this is significant because all my views say the same thing.